# When I use the document.write function to print the number in code below then it insert the 0 on right side of each output.Why it is happening?

Tags: javascript

When I use the `document.write` function to print the number in the code below, it inserts 0 to the right side of each output. Why is this happening? The code works as expected for the `alert` function.

```
    var number = Number(prompt("Please Enter a value"));
    if (number == 1)
    {
        alert("you Entered" + number);
         
        document.write("Your Entered Number is ="+number)
    }
    else
    {
        document.write(" Your Entered Number =" + number);
    }
```

Comment: You have stray characters in your code before `else`.

Comment: Works as expected. If you don't enter any thing it prints *0* because of `Number`. It gives default 0.

Comment: That code is fine. Runs as expected. You need to get rid of those two characters preceding the `else` clause though. Also its good practice to explicitly terminate that first invocation of `document.write()`

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in the comments, other than a few stray characters your code does what it intends to. I've included a slightly restructured code below.

```
function printNum (number) {
  // Ensure number is a number
  // (could use parseInt(number, 10) instead)
  if (typeof number === 'string')
    number = parseFloat(number);
  else if (typeof number !== 'number')
    return alert('printNum() requires a number'); // Alternatively throw an Error

  if (number === 1) alert('You entered ' + number);

  // Optional check number is not 0
  /* if (number === 0)
       return alert('printNum() doesn't like zero');
  */

  // We write to the document whether number is 1 or not
  document.write('Your number is ' + number);

});

// Call our function with an argument from prompt
printNum(prompt('Please Enter a numeric value'));
```

Comment: Why use `new Number`? `typeof new Number(1) === 'object'`